# Browserify change the order the dependencies are loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, browserify

The issue is Browserify loads bootstrap's javascript before loading jquery.

I have this in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "browserify app/scripts/main.js -o app/scripts/bundle.js"
},
```

and I require  dependencies in my main.js file like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap-sass');
var value = require('./test.js');
```

after I run **npm run build** I get my bundle.js file in which bootstrap script is first and jquery is second. That leads to a $ is undefined error, and of course to bootstrap scripts not working as they depend on jquery.

So, why is Browserify loading the files in this manner and how can I change it?

Comment: are you sure jquery is loaded ?

Comment: yes, jquery is concatenated in my bundle.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browserify will load your modules in order, but you have to pay attention to browser scripts which rely on the global scope to resolve their dependencies.

Bootstrap just references `$` and expects it to resolve to jQuery, so try this jazz by leaking jQuery into the global scope:

```
var jquery = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = jquery;

require('bootstrap-sass');
```